# I'm using a Roland TD-11KV Electric drum kit, and recording the toms sound different. Why is this?

Tags: drums, recording

I'm not sure if you guys can download the recording [here](https://www.facebook.com/download/721055874608914/toms%20test.wma), but please try.

All the drum pieces sound well, except for the toms. I wonder what's wrong?
Do any of you have experience recording with a Roland TD-11KV?

I'm using an M-Track audio interface. I'm recording at 2 channel, 24 bit, 44100Hz.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved it.

Apparently, the Roland TD-11 Drum Module itself is already an interface.

So what I did was to plug the Roland TD-11 Drum Module directly to my laptop, downloaded the Roland drivers from their website, and voila! It now works.

I believe the source of the problem was that I used XLR cables from Drum Module to the M-Track audio interface, whereas I should have used the 1/4" jacks instead.

Comment: `I believe the source of the problem was that I used XLR cables from Drum Module to the M-Track audio interface` The Roland TD-11KV sound module doesn't have XLR connection. Your problem was something else.

Comment: I used a 1/4" jack (connected to the module) with the other tip as XLR. The XLR tip was connected to the interface. Sorry if that wasn't clear. @JCPedroza